"Input needs to be a line layer" MMQGIS while using Animate lines
I'm trying to use MMQGIS Animate Lines function but keep getting error message "Input needs to be a line layer". The input layer is a line layer. I've tried linestring, multiline, shp file, geopackage. I'm out of ideas.
mmqgis_library.py code:
if (input_layer.type() != QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer) or\
   (input_layer.wkbType() not in [QgsWkbTypes.LineString, QgsWkbTypes.LineString25D, \
            QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString, QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString25D]):
    return "Input needs to be a line layer"

Using QGIS 3.34.3, updated plugin to latest.
